# Calling self.variable from another class

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I call variable from another class, I got 2 classes one is independent from another, but if something happens in first class I need reach label (self.lbl) in gui class and change it's value.

```
class MyCalendar(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)
        self.cal = CalendarCtrl(self, 10, wx.DateTime.Now(),style= CAL_MONDAY_FIRST)
        self.cal.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_CALENDAR, self.OnDate)

    def OnDate(self,event):

        if dateStatus:
            global beginDate
            tmp = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(self.cal.GetDate()), '%a %b %d %X %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            beginDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(tmp, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
            #DataList.renewlabels()    

        else: 
            global endDate
            tmp = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(self.cal.GetDate()), '%a %b %d %X %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            endDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(tmp, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
            #DataList.renewlabels()    
        wx.Window.Close(self)

class DataList(wx.Frame,): 
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title): 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(830, 440)) 
        self.Maximize(True)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        uber_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        top_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)


        right_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        #Labels
        self.beginlbl = wx.StaticText(panel ,-1,style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.ROMAN, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        self.beginlbl.SetLabel(str(beginDate))
        self.beginlbl.SetFont(font)
        self.endlbl = wx.StaticText(panel   ,-1,style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.endlbl.SetLabel(str(endDate))
        self.endlbl.SetFont(font)
        callCalendar() 

def callCalendar():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyCalendar(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()            


app = wx.App() 
dl = DataList(None, -1, 'Radar Report') 
dl.Show() 
app.MainLoop()
```

This is little bit of code to get idea what I have.

EDIT:
I missed  one method in **DataList** class, as you can see I call it in **MyCakendar.Ondate**

```
def renewlabels(self)
   self.beginlbl.SetLabel(str(beginDate))
```

Comment: Please give more info: what class needs to trigger the other's label ? what have you tried ? What is the expected output ?

Comment: I've done my best to fix your indentation. Please be very careful to reproduce your indentation accurately when posting Python code in future.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your needs correctly, you can pass the first class' instance as a parameter to the other class' method, where you can change it.

Here is an example.

```
class Class1():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class Class2():
    def change(self, instance):
        instance.a = 4

first = Class1(1)
print first.a

second = Class2()
second.change(first)

print first.a
```

So you can read or change a value in another class.